# LoadRunner soaptests as templates

Tags: soap, wsdl, loadrunner

I want to have my soap request saved as a template on the filesystem and have placeholders that could be replaced by substitutes with the editing of contracts/wsdl's.
Does Loadrunner support soap templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time.   I just use a standard web virtual user with a web custom request.   I load the file in the init phase of the script to avoid disk I/O on the load generator during the test and then reuse it over and over again for multiple iterations with multiple parameter sets.   See the C standard file I/O and memory management routines for loading the file and managing the memory.

In the source request file simply include your parameter markers "{paramname}" in the source file.

Works just fine.

Comment: James, could you please provide an example C code used to loading the file?

Comment: Look at the fopen() and fread() examples in the help file.   This should provide the first steps on the path.